# .NET Web API works on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I made a simple .net Web API on a windows that can connect to a database and can return a simple GET request. However, when I migrated this project over to my Mac, I can run the API but when I put in the GET request to retrieve info from the database I get this error:

"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to load the specified metadata resource.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException"

Any ideas? I've read that .net will not run on a Mac- but I'm seeing varying answers on whether this is true. I know when running the API on windows it opens a webpage that goes to a local host, but on Mac it uses a string of numbers to open up the api in the browser. Does this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is not cross-platform. You will need to use [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/).

A summary of the differences [from the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| ASP.NET Core                        | ASP.NET 4.x                      |
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Build for Windows, macOS, or Linux  | Build for Windows                |
| -                                   |                                  |
| Razor Pages is the recommended      | Use Web Forms, SignalR, MVC,     |
| approach to create a Web UI as      | Web API, WebHooks, or Web Pages  |
| of ASP.NET Core 2.x.                |                                  |
| See also MVC, Web API, and SignalR. |                                  |
| -                                   |                                  |
| Multiple versions per machine       | One version per machine          |
| -                                   |                                  |
| Develop with Visual Studio,         | Develop with Visual Studio using |
| Visual Studio for Mac, or           | C#, VB, or F#                    |
| Visual Studio Code using C# or F#   |                                  |
| -                                   |                                  |
| Higher performance than ASP.NET 4.x | Good performance                 |
| -                                   |                                  |
| Use .NET Core runtime               | Use .NET Framework runtime       |
+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```